# 'if window width' jquery command not responsive to changes in browser size. Need equivalent

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, resize, window, screen

In the following jQuery I aim to have my website 'animate' when on a 960px or larger screen, and fadein/out when on a screen smaller than 960px.

If I start my browser in a size above 960 the animate works as it should; nevertheless, when I resize my browser to under 960px it still animates the divs (instead of fadein/out). Nevertheless, if I resize the browser below 960px AND refresh, then fadein/out works (and if I then from here resize above 960px without refreshing, fadein/out remains instead of animate).

**So it appears the jQuery code I have used measures whatever the screen size is when the browser is opened/refreshed, and then operates accordingly - without adapting to any changes that would be made in browser size. This is a problem as I want the code to respond to any changes in browser size (without needing to refresh).**

Please help.

Culprits appear to be:

(A) **if ($(window).width() >= 960) {**

(B) **} else if ($(window).width() < 960) {**

JQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() >= 960) {     


$('a.forMovingPanel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if ($(".forMovingPanel").is(':animated')) return false;

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
        });

        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
    });


$('a.portfolioThumbs').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if ($(".portfolioThumbs").is(':animated')) return false;

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
                });

        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
    });



} else if ($(window).width() < 960) {

    $('a.forMovingPanel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if ($(".forMovingPanel").is(':animated')) return false;

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').fadeOut(200);
        });

        $target.addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
    }
});




   $("a.forMovingPanel").click(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   });


$('a.portfolioThumbs').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if ($(".portfolioThumbs").is(':animated')) return false;

     if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').fadeOut(200);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
        }
     });


     $("a.portfolioThumbs").click(function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need $( window ).resize() to do this. What I will do is

```
    $(window).ready(function(){

    foo();

    // the below is to call foo whenever window is resized
    $(window).resize(function() {
        foo();
    });

})

function foo(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 960) {    

        $('a.forMovingPanel').click(function() {
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $other = $target.siblings('.active');

            if ($(".forMovingPanel").is(':animated')) return false;

            if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
                $other.each(function(index, self) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                        left: $this.width()
                    }, 500);
                });

                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            }
        });


        $('a.portfolioThumbs').click(function() {
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $other = $target.siblings('.active');

            if ($(".portfolioThumbs").is(':animated')) return false;

            if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
                $other.each(function(index, self) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                        left: $this.width()
                    }, 500);
                        });

                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);
            }
        });



    } else if ($(window).width() < 960) {

        $('a.forMovingPanel').click(function() {
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $other = $target.siblings('.active');

            if ($(".forMovingPanel").is(':animated')) return false;

            if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
                $other.each(function(index, self) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass('active').fadeOut(200);
                });

                $target.addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
            }
        });




       $("a.forMovingPanel").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
       });


        $('a.portfolioThumbs').click(function() {
            var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
                $other = $target.siblings('.active');

            if ($(".portfolioThumbs").is(':animated')) return false;

             if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
                $other.each(function(index, self) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.removeClass('active').fadeOut(200);
                    });

                    $target.addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
                }
             });


            $("a.portfolioThumbs").click(function(ev) {
               ev.preventDefault();
            });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Did not work :( When I resize my browser from above 960px to under 960px (without refreshing) it still animates the divs instead of fadeing them in/out. Any idea why?

Comment: Have a look at this js fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/realtymarker/07dLf1mj/3/)